# How to get the json object from an form exception some especial name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some input in my form,now I want to get the json object from the form without some input named point,What's wrong with my code?I have to remove them.It seems not work for `not()` function.How to fix my code?

```
<form id="myform">
<input name='student' value='a'/> 
<input name='student' value='b'/> '
 ...
 <input name='point' value='90'/> 
<input name='point' value='95'/> 
</form>
```

Now I only want to submit the student data to the server.So I write the code:

```
  var data = $('#myform').not("input[name='point']").serializeArray();
            var objParam = {};
            $.each(data, function(i, v) { 
                objParam[v.name] = v.value;
            });
```

but the result still have point data.What's wrong with `not()` function?

Comment: Your current selector says "serialise #myform which does not also match the selector `input[name=point]`. It's filtering the form, not the children of the form.

Comment: `$('#myform').not("input[name='point']")` means "Select the form with an ID of 'myForm'. Then, from this selection, exclude all `input` with name=point". The problem is that the selection contains only one element (`form` as a whole), no `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you.

`$('#myform input[name!=point]').serializeArray()`

Answer (score 2):

breaking down your code `$('#myform')` selects your form, in this case, only one object, then you filter that object with `.not("input[name='point']")` but there is only one object which is the form itself.

You want to filter the form's children instead, so just add .children() like this:

```
var data = $('#myform').children().not("input[name='point']").serializeArray();
            var objParam = {};
            $.each(data, function(i, v) { 
                objParam[v.name] = v.value;
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is faulty.

```
$('#myform').not("input[name='point']").serializeArray()
```

...says, "Serialise the form with ID 'myForm' which is not also an input and has the name 'point'.

Rather, you mean: "Serialise the form with ID 'myForm' but omit its child inputs with name 'point'.

Here's a non-jQuery way, using native [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

```
//get the form as form data
var fd = new FormData(document.querySelector('#myform'));

//delete any elements pertaining to [name=point]
fd.delete('point');

//et voila; this shows we retain only the student fields
for (var key of fd.keys()) alert(key);
```

Comment: Do this way really remove the element from the UI ?

Comment: No - it wasn't clear from your question that that was your intention. I thought you simply didn't want to *submit* those values. If you want to remove it from the UI, you can use jQuery `remove()` on the elements then run `serialize()` on the form.